# Can a small UAV restart its engine in mid-flight?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, piston-engine

Is it possible for a small UAV, say a small piston-engine aircraft with a low windmilling effect, to restart its engine in mid-flight following an engine shutoff?

Comment: With most hobby motors, no, this isn't possible. Some larger motors can be made with an electric start but there is no "ignition" like on regular aircraft. Usually the hobby motors stop when the gas runs out/is turned off. They start either by hand propping or by using an electric "starter".

Comment: Depends on the aircraft and engine in question.

Answer (score 2):

Some gliders have pop-up engines to extend range if they cant't catch rising air (known as turbo-sustainers) which start by in-flight windmilling, but I wouldn't count on it with an engine not designed to be started this way. Additionally, if the shutoff was not intentional it seems likely that whatever caused the engine to fail will make it even harder to start in this manner.